# Show that on $[0,1]$, locally constant $C^1$ function must be globally constant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f \in C^1[0,1]$.

If for all $x_0\in[0,1]$, there is an open subset $U\subset [0,1]$ such that   $x_0\in U$  and $\forall x\in U,f(x)=f(x_0)$.

How can I show that $\forall x,y\in [0,1],f(x)=f(y)$ ?

I tried to use the finite cover, but I failed to construct a contradiction.But I still think the finite cover is useful for this question.

Comment: *Hint:* Look at the maximum and minimum points of $f$.

Comment: Most of us will think that the hypothesis that $f$ is continuously differentiable rather silly.  But, if we were willing to play that game, then clearly the hypothesis implies that $f'(x)=0$ for every $x$ and so on....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually $f$ doesn't need to be $C^1$, or even continuous a priori.

For every $x\in [0,1]$ pick an open $U_x\subset [0,1]$ such that $f$ is constant on $U_x$. Then the family $(U_x)_{x\in [0,1]}$ covers $[0,1]$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there is a finite subcovering, say by $U_{x_1}, \dots, U_{x_n}$.

$U_{x_1}$ must intersect at least one of $U_{x_2},\dots U_{x_n}$ because $[0,1]$ is connected (so it can't be the union of the two non-empty disjoint open sets given by $U_{x_1}$ and $U_{x_2}\cup\cdots\cup U_{x_n}$).

Say, wlog., that it intersects $U_{x_2}$. Since $f$ is constant on both $U_{x_1}$ and $U_{x_2}$ it must be constant on $U_{x_1}\cup U_{x_2}$. Now again, $U_{x_1}\cup U_{x_2}$ must intersect one of the remaining sets $U_{x_3},\dots,U_{x_n}$ by connectedness, say wlog. that it is $U_{x_3}$, etc.

Inductively we get that $f$ is constant on all of $U_{x_1}\cup\cdots\cup U_{x_n}=[0,1]$.